# dd/mm/yyyy and hh:mm:ss to yyyymmddhhmmss

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-2007

[excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg2bC.png)

Column A is date, column B is format of date i want.

For converting it i have attached vba code:

```
Sub dateformat()

Dim ws As Worksheet    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd;@"
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Result 1:
This code gives me column B

When I am changing the format of column B to make it merge with time:

It is showing like Column C(date format):

```
Sub a()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate    
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Select 'or 

Worksheets("SheetName").Range("b:b").Select    
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"    
End Sub
```

I want to merge date with time = `dd/mm/yy` (column 1), `hh:mm:ss`(column 2) to  `yyyymmddhhmmss`(column 3).

Comment: where do you keep the time ? what column ? wher are the values ?

Comment: if at Column A you keep dates (`dd/mm/yy`) and in Column B you keep the time (`hh:mm:ss`), and you want to merge them to Column `C`. you need to loop thorugh the rows, and then for each cell in Column C write down `ws.Cells(i, "C") = Format(ws.Cells(i, "A"), "yyyymmdd") & Format(ws.Cells(i, "B"), "hhmmss")` and format it as integer to show as you wanted : `ws.Cells(i, "C").NumberFormat = "0"` . Or you can use a Non-VBA solution by writing a formula in Column C `=TEXT(A1+B1,"mmddyyhhmmss")` and drag it down

Comment: Sub table() ///
 
///Dim ws As Worksheet
///Dim i As Long

///For Each i In ws
    /// ws.Cells(i, "C") = Format(ws.Cells(i, "A"), "yyyymmdd") & ///Format(ws.Cells(i, "B"), "hhmmss")
     ///ws.Cells(i, "C").NumberFormat = "0"
///Next i

///End Sub     
showing error. could u plz correct it

Comment: actually i have 5000 cells so it will take time to drag down all.

i will be happy if u solve my problem using VBA.

Comment: then use the formula on cell C1 `=TEXT(A1+B1,"mmddyyhhmmss")` and drag it down all the way

Answer (score 0):

So after clarifying what you were after I think this should work, given that the data is actually in a date and time format.

```
Sub combine()
Dim str1, str2 As String

'Making sure you're only applying it to the cells that have date/time next to them
lastrow1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'Defining your ranges
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastrow1)
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & lastrow1)
Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C" & lastrow1)

rng1.NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
rng2.NumberFormat = "hhmmss"
rng3.NumberFormat = "@"

For i = 1 To lastrow1
str1 = Range("A" & i).Text
str2 = Range("B" & i).Text

Range("C" & i) = str1 & str2
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: yes,but i want date in (yyyymmdd)
eg:yyyymmddhhmmss

Comment: Did it work? If so it'd be great to mark the question as solved